# Vector3 Directional Property Values

Tags: c#, vector, directx-11

I haven't been able to find documentation on this (may just not be entering the correct [search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=iv9hW4njEuWb5wKLv7EQ&q=Vector3%20properties%20DirectX%2011&oq=Vector3%20properties%20DirectX%2011&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l3.301232.307986.0.308149.29.25.0.0.0.0.471.2932.2j7j2j3j1.15.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..14.15.2931...0j0i67k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j33i160k1.0.DqZ-2rlBxEk) terms in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=rf1hW-OjKs2e5gLq4afoDg&q=Vector3.ForwardRH%20value%20directx&oq=Vector3.ForwardRH%20value%20directx&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1l2.2363.3592.0.3861.8.8.0.0.0.0.193.787.0j5.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.4.658...33i21k1.0.OAuJSipujMk)). I am currently re-writing an in-house camera and am wondering what the values for `Vector3.ForwardRH` and `Vector3.ForwardLH` are. I already know the values for [`Left`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-left.html), [`Right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html), [`Up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-up.html), and [`Down`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-down.html) which are simplistic enough given a traditional `Vector3`:

```
Vector3.Left  = (-1,  0, 0);
Vector3.Right = ( 1,  0, 0);
Vector3.Up    = ( 0,  1, 0);
Vector3.Down  = ( 0, -1, 0);
```

I also know that in `Unity` the `Vector3` class has the properties `forward` and `back` which correspond to the `Z` axis respectively:

```
Vector3.Forward  = (0, 0,  1);
Vector3.Backward = (0, 0, -1);
```

***Question***: However, DirectX 11 has two properties for both `forward` and `back` which are the `LH` and `RH` variants. Does anyone have any documentation on what these values are and why `LH` and `RH` are different? Why do most modern engines simply use [`forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) and [`back`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-back.html) instead?

***NOTE*** :Thank you all for your help, if you feel like I need to add more information to this post to clarify it further, please feel free to let me know in a comment and I will do my best to flesh it out further.

***ALSO***: The links to `Google` are my actual searches.

***The Answer***: `LH` and `RH` represent the differences between left-handed and right-handed coordinate systems. The `Forward` property needs to be chosen based on your coordinate system in DirectX. For example, my coordinate system is right-handed so I need to use `ForwardRH` and `BackwardRH`.

Comment: Those properties are for the right-hand (RH) and left-hand (LH) coordinate systems, and the Z axis will point in the opposite direction depending on which coordinate system you use.  Unity just uses the left-hand coordinate system.

Comment: So based on this, I can assume that `ForwardLH` and `ForwardRH` are going to be the proper value (e.g. 0, 0, 1) for their respective coordinate systems?

Comment: If you can add that as an answer then I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: Some engines (Unity) just say, "We're using right-handed coordinates. Have fun." Others offer some flexibility. The name comes from right-hand rule vs left-hand rule, I believe.

Comment: That I understand, for instance, in mathematics everything is in the right-handed coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LH and RH stand for left-hand and right-hand coordinate systems, respectively.  The Z axis will point in opposite directions depending on which coordinate system you use.  DirectX doesn't know which system you're using, so it provides both constants for convenience and readability.

Other game engines (e.g. Unity) provide only a single constant because they assume everyone is using the same coordinate system.

Comment: Is it that they assume the same coordinate system is used? I could have swore they just sent everything to DirectX behind the scenes in right-handed coordinates? Thank you for solving my issue!

Comment: Yes.  If you wanted to use different coordinates then you could probably make it to work, but the code would look odd in places.

Comment: The choice of RH vs. LH is entirely arbitrary. Historically, OpenGL uses right-handed coordinates, column-major matrices,  column vectors, and post-multiplication. Historically, DirectX uses left-handed coordinates, row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication.  XNA Game Studio went with right-handed coordinates, row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication because it was felt it was more intuitive for beginners, and Unity 3D copied that design. With modern programmable shaders, it doesn't matter at all... you just need to pick one and use it throughout your program.

Comment: For all the details on the various conventions here, see [this blog post](http://www.seanmiddleditch.com/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/). [DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) uses row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication and has both LH and RH versions of all functions where handedness matters which covers both historic DirectX and XNA Game Studio scenarios. HLSL defaults to column-major matrices, so you typically just transpose the matrix as you put it into CBs.